# Setting scale range for labels in KML files using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, kml, scale

Is there a way for labels to be displayed in KML only when zoomed in (or out) beyond a certain scale range, just as it is possible in ArcMap?

If exporting to KML from ArcGIS, I guess the first step is to label the features before exporting.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest thing to scale dependent layers in KML is [Regions](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/regions).

However, Layer To KML does not write them and I do not think they would support the concept of scale dependent labels.  There is a document on [KML support in ArcGIS](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/00s2/00s200000005000000.htm) that mentions that regions are not written.

> Examples of KML items not supported in exported KML files include
>   COLLADA, regions, and time spans (animations).